# Can't populate variable inside FOR command/loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, batch-processing

I can't seem to populate a variable once inside the `FOR` command.

Here's the relevant code:

---

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set rpath= 
for /r "%DNGfolder%" %%a in (*.dng) do (
    echo %%~pa
    set rpath=%%~pa
    echo %rpath%
    set rpath=rpath:DNG=RAW%
    echo %rpath%%%~na.*
    )
```

---

In the above, the `echo` lines exist only so that I can see what's going on... they'll be removed once everything is working properly.

What I need is to populate the variable `rpath` with the path that's returned in the `%%~pa` variable, but no matter what I've tried, I can't get `rpath` to populate with any values at all... not even when I put a line in there that reads set `rpath=xxx`.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated as I've wasted hours searching numerous places for an answer/solution and am at my wit's end.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need some knowledge about `delayed expansion` ....

Comment: yes indeed I do, but your comment isn't helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that variables can't be populated while inside the **for** loop, but they can be populated via a subroutine call from within the **for** loop.

By passing the values returned in the **for** loop to the subroutine, I was able to assign those values to variables.

Here's the revised code:

```
set rpath=
for /r  %DNGfolder% %%a in (*.dng) do (
    call :rpathname "%%a" "%%~pa" "%%~na" "%%~da"
    )
endlocal

goto :EOF

:rpathname

set drvltr=%4
set rpath=%2
set fnm=%3
set drvltr=%drvltr:"=%
set rpath=%rpath:DNG=RAW%
set rpath=%rpath:"=%
set fnm=%fnm:"=%
del "%drvltr%%rpath%%fnm%.*"
echo.
echo.

goto :EOF
```

The objective was to delete files in one directory which bore the same filename as files in another directory, and the above code did the trick

Answer (score 4):

Replace this:

```
echo %rpath%
set rpath=rpath:DNG=RAW%
echo %rpath%%%~na.*
```

with this:

```
echo !rpath!
set rpath=!rpath:DNG=RAW!
echo !rpath!%%~na.*
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is not echoing the text, the problem is that I'm unable to assign values to variables while in the "for" loop.

Comment: You don't know enough to understand what your problem is.  Sorry but it is the delayed expansion that allows the use of variables within a loop.  My answer corrects your syntax and allows you to use the variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
set "FolderA=X:\Path to\FolderA"    
set "FolderB=X:\Path to\FolderB"    
for %%a in ("%FolderA%\*") do if exist "%FolderB%\%%~nxa" del "%FolderB%\%%~nxa"
```